# Angular event won't fire when clicking on svg

Tags: html, css, angular

I have an angular (4) based web app, with an [`@angular/material`](https://material.angular.io/components/card/overview) based card view. Embedded in the content of the card view is a sub-component, which just displays an svg as an `<object>`.

Here is what that card looks like:

```
<md-card (click)="onSelect(line)">
    <md-card-content (click)="onSelect(line)">
        <app-line-overview [line]="line"></app-line-overview>
    </md-card-content>
    <md-card-footer>
        <h2>{{line.name}}</h2>
        <h3>OEE: {{line.oee}}</h3>
    </md-card-footer>
</md-card>
```

The issue is that the `(click)` event doesn't work if I click on the svg image (presumably because it is on top of the card view?), but if I click around the svg, the event fires.

I tried the adding `md-card { z-index: 999 }` to the css, but it makes no difference. How can I ensure that clicking anywhere within the card fires the event regardless of what is inside it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe writing a directive with a listener on clicks would help :

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[clickInside]'
})
export class ClickInsideDirective {
    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
    }

    @Output()
    public clickInside = new EventEmitter<Event>();


        @HostListener('click', ['$event', '$event.target'])
            public onClick(event: MouseEvent, targetElement: HTMLElement): void {
                if (!targetElement) {
                    return;
                }

                const clickedInside = this.elementRef.nativeElement.contains(targetElement);
                if (clickedInside) {
                    this.clickOutside.emit(event);
                }
            }
    ...
}
```

usage

```
<md-card (clickInside)="onSelect(line)">
```